# How to know whether late init has been initialized in dart(flutter)?

Tags: flutter, http, dart, lateinit

I am fetching data from url in Flutter. I have a late init Map called tables. I am fetching data inside initState() function. When I first launch the app, I am getting LateInizialization error on the red screen. I want to detect whether late init is initialized and display spinner if it is not initialized. This is my code.

```
class TablesTab extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TablesTabState createState() => _TablesTabState();
}

class _TablesTabState extends State<TablesTab> {
  late List<dynamic> tables;
  var refreshKey = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();
  GetUriData tablesInstance = new GetUriData(url: '/api/table/getAllTables');

  void getTables() async {
    tables = await tablesInstance.getData();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getTables();
  }

  Future<void> refreshList() async {
    refreshKey.currentState?.show(atTop: false);
    // await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    var updatedTables = await tablesInstance.getData();
    setState(() {
      tables = updatedTables;
    });

    //network call and setState so that view will render the new values
    print(tables);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: RefreshIndicator(
          child:  GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 4,
            children: List.generate(this.tables.length, (index) {
              return Center(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/tableReview', arguments: {'table': this.tables[index]});
                  },
                  child: Container(
                      width: 80,
                      height: 80,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, width: 2.0),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(70))
                      ),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            '${this.tables[index]['tableNum']}',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                fontSize: 23
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
          ),
          onRefresh: refreshList
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13):

You can't know whether `late` field initialized or not.

I don't think you should use `late` in that case. Adding `late` to field means that the field will be initialized when you use it for the first time. In your code the field can be not initialized, so you'd better to use `tables` without `late`, initialize it with empty list and use boolean flag to indicate loading:

```dart
  var tables = [];
  var loading = false;

  ...

  Future<void> refreshList() async {
    ...
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });
    var updatedTables = await tablesInstance.getData();
    setState(() {
      tables = updatedTables;
      loading = false;
    });
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you :)

Comment: use `late` when you strongly convinced that first time you use late field it will be initialized. And always remember that using `late` makes you code less safe and adds possibility of runtime errors.

Answer (score 7):

You can't check the initialization state of a `late` variable.  If that's something you need to know, you either will need to add and maintain a separate flag or make the variable nullable and compare to `null` instead.

> I want to detect whether late init is initialized and display spinner if it is not initialized.

In your case you probably should use a [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

Comment: Thnx. But when am I supposed to use late init then?

Comment: You'd use `late` when you can logically *guarantee* that the variable won't be used before it's initialized. One example would be a member that must be initialized within the constructor body (and can't be initialized from the initializer list).

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer, in my case, it is not about the mapController, it is about size
I added `Flexible` as parent of `FlutterMap` and map showing perfect

Try below code:

```
Flexible(
  child: FlutterMap(
    options: MapOptions(
      center: LatLng(51.5, -0.09),
      zoom: 5.0,
    ),
    layers: [
      TileLayerOptions(
        urlTemplate:
            'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        tileProvider:
            NonCachingNetworkTileProvider(),
      ),
      MarkerLayerOptions(markers: [])
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give any default value in the constructor if you are using late initializer or you can make them nullable but making nullable is hectic

Answer (score 0):

You can.

```
class MyClass {
  late double myLateField;
  bool _isInitialized = false;

  void myFunction() {
    if (!_isInitialized) {
      _isInitialized = true;
      // ... init your late field.
    }
  }

}
```

As others have said, you probably shouldn't do this. But technically, it's possible with this workaround.