# the operand can't be null

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

This condition:

```
@override
Widget build(context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: buildSearchField(),
  body:
      searchResultsFuture == null ? buildNoCont() : buildSearchRes(),
);}}
```

throws this error:

```
The operand can't be null, so the condition is always false.
Try removing the condition, an enclosing condition, or the whole conditional statement.
```

It's declared like this:

```
late Future<QuerySnapshot> searchResultsFuture;
```

I'm already importing the cloud_firestore package.

I've tried everything that is available and still get this error, and I need to keep the condition.

Comment: Show us where you update `searchResultsFuture`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the reason is the variable is declared as a [late](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#late-variables) instantiation. Here is a good post/reference on finding out if [late variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66776596/how-to-know-whether-late-init-has-been-initialized-in-dartflutter) have been initialized.

In your case (see docs reference)

> Because the type checker can’t analyze uses of fields and top-level
> variables, it has a conservative rule that non-nullable fields have to
> be initialized either at their declaration (or in the constructor
> initialization list for instance fields). So Dart reports a compile
> error on this class.

**Solution:**

> You can fix the error by making the field nullable and then using null
> assertion operators on the uses:

You have 2 options.

First, (assuming you are extending a [Stateful](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) widget), you can override the [initState()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html) function with:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState(); // this must always be first
    searchResultsFuture = //insert you future here
  }
```

alternatively, you can use the null-safety implemenation by declaring your Future as nullable:

```
Future<QuerySnapshot>? searchResultsFuture;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! declaring the Future as nullable worked. I'm still learning and I was looking in the wrong place.