# The operand can't be null, so the condition is always false. I am receiving this warning

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-layout, flutter-design

I have made a BMI calculator in flutter. I am new in flutter. After running the code i am receiving the above warning. Kindly provide me the solution of this problem. Below attached is the link of the code

[Link of the dart file](https://gist.github.com/ImVasav/ffced1f137024b51499dafa646ab70f0)

Comment: Please when posting code, copy paste the code into a code block, don't link it outside, it helps us help you

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68321491/10740241. The problem seems to be 'late'

Comment: Yeah it did help. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You are declaring the `_result` variable as non-nullable,

```dart
 late double _result;
```

However you do a `null` check

```dart
null == _result ? "Enter Value" : _result.toStringAsFixed(2),
```

So change your variable declaration to this,

```dart
double? _result;
```

And then you can `null` check this way

```dart
 _result?.toStringAsFixed(2) ?? "Enter Value" ,
```

Comment: This Helped me. The warning is removed.

Answer (score 3):

You declared the result variable like this:

```
late double _result;
```

`_result` is the name of the variable, `double` is the type.

`late` means you are not yet assigning a value to it.

A late variable is different from a nullable variable in the sense that a nullable variable's value could be null, a late variable doesn't have a value until you assign one.

```
late int xd;

if (xd == null) {
}
```

the above if will always be false because `xd`'s value is not null, xd has no value at all.

a nullable variable is determined with a `?` after the type:

```
double? _result;
```

which means that if you haven't assigned anything to it, it will be null, but you can also assign null directly.

```
_result = null;
```

the above is not possible for a `late` variable.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the `extractedData` to `jsonDecode(response.body)`

from

```
if (extractedData == null)
```

to

```
if (jsonDecode(response.body) == null)
```